# variable templates compile time array

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm currently learning about template meta-programming in c++ and stumbled across variable templates. As a fun exercise, I decided to implement compile time static array with following usage -

```
my_array<1,2,3,4> arr;  // gives an array with 4 members = 1,2,3,4
```

I've tried several iterations of my attempt, removing syntax errors along the way but now I'm stuck since no compiler gives useful warning. Here's my current code -

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t... Enteries>
constexpr size_t my_array[sizeof...(Enteries)] = {Enteries...};

int main() {
    my_array<1,2,3,4,5,6> arr;
}
```

but currently it gives following error with clang -

```
static_array.cpp:7:10: error: expected ';' after expression
        my_array<1,2,3,4,5,6> arr;
                ^
                ;
static_array.cpp:7:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'arr'
        my_array<1,2,3,4,5,6> arr;
                              ^
static_array.cpp:7:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        my_array<1,2,3,4,5,6> arr;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

and with gcc -

```
static_array.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
static_array.cpp:7:24: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘arr’
  my_array<1,2,3,4,5,6> arr;
                        ^~~
static_array.cpp:7:27: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
  my_array<1,2,3,4,5,6> arr;
```

How should I proceed forward to implement this thing(preferably with variable templates since I know this can be implemented with old struct technique).

Comment: `my_array<1,2,3,4,5,6>` is the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to make a type?

```
#include <stdexcept>

template < size_t... Enteries >
class my_array
{
    constexpr static size_t const N = sizeof...(Enteries);
    constexpr static size_t const value[N] = {Enteries...};
public:
    constexpr size_t operator[](size_t idx) const
    {
      if ( idx < N )
        return value[idx];
      else
        throw std::out_of_range("my_array index out of range");;
    }
};

int main() {
    my_array<1,2,3,4,5,6> arr;
    static_assert( arr[0] == 1, "!" );
    static_assert( arr[1] != 5, "!!" );
  //static_assert( arr[9] == 0, "!!!" ); // Does not compile
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments to the question, `my_array<1,2,3,4,5,6>` isn't a type. `my_array` is a variable template, it has a type you can use once specialized but it is not a type, you cannot use it the way you are doing.
You cannot declare variables having type `my_array<1,2,3,4>`, but you can use the variable `my_array<1,2,3,4>`.
As an example, do you want to get the N-th element? `my_array<1,2,3,4,5,6>[N];`.

Sample program:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t... Enteries>
constexpr size_t my_array[sizeof...(Enteries)] = {Enteries...};

int main() {
   std::cout << my_array<1,2,3,4,5,6>[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches to compile-time arrays

### With `constexpr`

Just qualify an array with `constexpr`

```
constexpr size_t arr[] = {3, 2, 1};
```

### With variable templates

```
template<size_t... E>
constexpr size_t arr[] = {E...};
```

This is known as a [variable template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template), `arr` *is the variable*, therefore you would use it like one

```
for(auto i : arr<42, 420, 4200>)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

[Live](http://ideone.com/uPIkFE)

### With non-type template parameters

This functionality is provided in C++14 already, namely [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence). This is not as straightforward as a simple array and is used mostly when you need a parameter pack of numbers

```
template<typename T, T... I>
void print(std::integer_sequence<T, I...>)
{
    (std::cout << ... << I);  // fold expression from C++1z, parentheses required
}

print(std::integer_sequence<size_t, 1, 2, 3>{});
```

[Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sMxXJfsMtXJv9viK)